# Show Html Page in my iPhone view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

I tried to show an `html` page that is inside my app, but it did not show on the view:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abt.html"];
NSURLRequest *documentsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] ;

[_webview loadRequest:documentsRequest] ;
```

I followed this link:  [iOS - display content from an html resource file or remote webpage in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578027/ios-display-content-from-an-html-resource-file-or-remote-webpage-in-a-webview)

by Matt Gibson

Please let me know how to show.

thanks

Comment: there could be a lot of things wrong here...webView may not be initialising properly, the "Path" variable might be empty..You need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your html page is inside the app so try this one, I have used it and it's work fine.

```
 NSString *htmlFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abt" ofType:@"html"];
 NSString *htmlString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:Nil];
 [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```